# The points shows the NaN error when i enter a word

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i enter a word this shows me the error of NaN in alert. The success message shows the correct value but the alert shows the NaN error. The `points` and `totalPoints` are declared outside the function scope

```js
   var wordList = ["jalapeno", "nopal", "jalap", "paeon", "panel", "pelon", "penal", "plena", "pleon", "plane"]
var wordInput = $('#word-input');
var totalPoints = 0; // initialize total points variable
var points = 0;

var notEmpty = function(message) {
  $('.sb-message-box').addClass('error-message').text(message);
  // $('.sb-hive-input-content').addClass('not-empty').text(message); 
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#word-input').val('');
    // $('.sb-hive-input-content').removeClass('not-empty').text('');
    $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('error-message').text('');
  }, 1000);
}

var hasError = function(message) {
  $('.sb-message-box').addClass('error-message').text(message);
  $('.sb-hive-input-content').addClass('has-error').text(message);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#word-input').val('');
    $('.sb-hive-input-content').removeClass('has-error').text('');
    $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('error-message').text('');
  }, 1000);
}

var successMessage = function(message) {
  $('.sb-message-box').addClass('success-message').text(message);
  $('.sb-message-box').addClass('sb-message').text(message);
  $('.sb-hive-input-content').addClass('isAccepting').text();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#word-input').val('');
    $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('success-message').text('');
    $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('sb-message').text('');
    $('.sb-hive-input-content').removeClass('isAccepting').text();
  }, 1000);
}

// Define click function for enter-btn
$('#enter-btn').click(function() {

  var word = wordInput.text().trim();
  var centerLetter = $('.hive-cell.center .cell-letter').text();

  console.log(word)


  // Statements & conditions
  if (word.trim().length === 0) {
    notEmpty('Enter a word');

  } else if (word.length <= 3) {
    $('.sb-hive-input-placeholder').text(word);
    hasError('Too short');

  } else if (word.indexOf(centerLetter) === -1) {
    $('.sb-hive-input-placeholder').text(word);
    hasError('Missing center letter');

  } else if (word.length > 3 && !wordList.includes(word.toLowerCase())) {
    $('.sb-hive-input-placeholder').text(word);
    // hiveInput.removeClass('sb-hive-input-placeholder');
    hasError('Not in word list');

  } else if (wordList.includes(word.toLowerCase()) && !result.includes(word.toLowerCase())) {

    // Get letter count of the word

    var letterCount = word.length;
    if (letterCount === 4) {
      points = 1;
      successMessage('Good! ' + points + 'point.');
    } else if (letterCount === 5) {
      points = 5;
      successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' points.');
    } else if (letterCount === 6) {
      points = 6;
      successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' points.');
    } else if (letterCount === 7) {
      points = 7;
      successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' points.');
    } else if (letterCount === 8) {
      // Checks if the word is a pangram
      points = 15;
      successMessage('Got a pangram! 15 points!');
    } else {
      successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' letters. Keep going!');
    }
    alert(points);
    console.log(points);
    totalPoints = totalPoints + points;
  }
});

    // Create and Set Cookie
    function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, daysToExpire, path) {
        var date = new Date();
    
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (daysToExpire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + JSON.stringify(cookieValue) + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";   path=" + path ;
        console.log("setCookieValue: " + JSON.stringify(cookieValue));
    }
    
    setCookie('Result', result, 1, '/');
```

Comment: You have `totalpoint` and `totalPoints`, which are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never save your point value to your totalPoints value, so totalPoints can't stack up. On top of that you need to place your storage variable outside of your function scope. In your case you would simply set totalPoints to 0 everytime you call your function.

So a solution would be:

```js
        var totalPoints = 0; // initialize total points variable
        let wordList = ["test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "testtest"] // Changed
        let result = [] // Changed
        
        // Define click function for enter-btn
        $('#enter-btn').click(function() {   
          let points = 0; // Changed
          let wordInput = document.getElementById("inputTxt") // Changed
          var word = wordInput.value.trim(); // Changed
          var centerLetter = $('.hive-cell.center .cell-letter').text();

          // functions
          var notEmpty = function(message) { 
              $('.sb-message-box').addClass('error-message').text(message); 
                  // $('.sb-hive-input-content').addClass('not-empty').text(message); 
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#word-input').val('');
                  // $('.sb-hive-input-content').removeClass('not-empty').text('');
                      $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('error-message').text('');
              }, 1000); 
          } 

          var hasError = function(message) { 
              $('.sb-message-box').addClass('error-message').text(message);
                  $('.sb-hive-input-content').addClass('has-error').text(message); 
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#word-input').val('');
                      $('.sb-hive-input-content').removeClass('has-error').text('');
                          $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('error-message').text('');
              }, 1000); 
          } 

          var successMessage = function(message) { 
                  $('.sb-message-box').addClass('success-message').text(message); 
                  $('.sb-message-box').addClass('sb-message').text(message); 
                      $('.sb-hive-input-content').addClass('isAccepting').text(); 
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#word-input').val('');
                      $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('success-message').text('');
                      $('.sb-message-box').removeClass('sb-message').text('');
                          $('.sb-hive-input-content').removeClass('isAccepting').text(); 
                  }, 1000); 
          }

          // Statements & conditions
          if (word.trim().length === 0) { 
              notEmpty('Enter a word');

          } else if (word.length <= 3) { 
              $('.sb-hive-input-placeholder').text(word); 
              hasError('Too short'); 

          } else if (word.indexOf(centerLetter) === -1) { 
              $('.sb-hive-input-placeholder').text(word); 
              hasError('Missing center letter'); 

          } else if (word.length > 3 && !wordList.includes(word.toLowerCase())) { 
              $('.sb-hive-input-placeholder').text(word);
              // hiveInput.removeClass('sb-hive-input-placeholder');
              hasError('Not in word list');

          } else if (wordList.includes(word.toLowerCase()) && !result.includes(word.toLowerCase())) {

          // Get letter count of the word

          var letterCount = word.length;
          if (letterCount === 4) {
              points = 1;
              successMessage('Good! ' + points + 'point.');
          } else if (letterCount === 5) {
              points = 5;
              successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' points.');
          } else if (letterCount === 6) {
              points = 6;
              successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' points.');
          } else if (letterCount === 7) {
              points = 7;
              successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' points.');
          } else if (letterCount === 8) {
              // Checks if the word is a pangram
              points = 15;
              successMessage('Got a pangram! 15 points!');
          } else {
              successMessage('Good! ' + letterCount + ' letters. Keep going!');
          }
          //alert(points);
          console.log("new points: " + points);
          totalPoints += points;
          console.log("totalPoints: " + totalPoints);
          result.push(word.toLowerCase())
          }
        })
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<input name="inputTxt" type="text" id="inputTxt"/>
<button id="enter-btn">Add</button>
```

Added an input for testing

Added new code to snippet and got it working, added a few missing variables needed for the intended functionality (as far as i can get it).

If you got any more issues you are either not showing your full code or you are giving the input some strange words that it's unable to process.

For testing please note that only words giving in the wordlist can be used and an already processed word goes to the result array and cant be used afterwards.

Comment: I want to add the points of previous entered word and new word to the totalPoints variable. I tried your code snippet but it doesn't work

Comment: Please try to further explain your problem/what you want to achieve. Is it only the last entered word and the new one? And are all older words to ignore?

Comment: Let us suppose i enter 5 words of different letterCount. When i enter a word, add its point to the totalPoints variable. Same for all 5 words.  I want to add the points of all 5 words to the totalPoints variable.  But the problem is when i enter a word, it shows the words point and for second word the points count start from zero. The points are not stored in totalPoints variable.

Comment: I added an input to the code snippet, are you sure its not working? Keep in mind that you only count your points when your word has 4,5 or 8 letters. Every other length it wont get any points.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Its working now. I have declare the totalPoints variable inside the function scope

Comment: The points shows the error of NaN when i enter a word

Comment: In your own code or in the snippet? Please provide more code samples describing your problem.

Comment: yes it is working now

Comment: I have one more question related to cookie. I have create a setCookie function. I want to create a getCookie function to get the value of cookie when page reload. How can i do this

Comment: I think this is stuff for a new question, you should first close this question as finished because your original problem is solved

Comment: i have asked the new question please check